# How to get all model validation errors in ASP.NET api

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api, model, modelstate

My model looks like this:

```cs
public class Meeting : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Start_time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string End_time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Url]
    public string Url { get; set; }
        
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[(a-zA-Z)' '(a-zA-Z)]*$", ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[(a-zA-Z)' '(a-zA-Z)]*$", ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
    public string Participant { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        DateTime dt, dt1;
        if(DateTime.TryParse(Start_time, out dt) == false)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Start time wrong", new[] { "Start time" }));
        }
            
        if (DateTime.TryParse(End_time, out dt1) == false)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("End time wrong", new[] { "End time" }));
        }
            
        if (string.Compare(Start_time, End_time) == 1)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Time Conflict", new[] { "Time" }));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

And I don't know how to get all errors in JSON both from model itself and `IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate` method

My POST method has this realization:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Meeting meet)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Guid obj = Guid.NewGuid();
        meet.Id = obj.ToString();
        _dataAccessProvider.AddMeetingRecord(meet);
        return Ok("Meeting was successfully added");
    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

I tried to use `IEnumerable<ModelError> allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);` and return `allErrors` in BadRequest but it didn't work

Comment: what do you mean by `didn't work`? there is no error at all?

Comment: @KingKing No improves, didn't solve my problem. For example if I have errors in Owner and in Start_time, I will see only Owner error (but if I give proper value to Owner, after that I could see Start_time error)

Comment: Have you tried using a yield return in place of storing validations in a list ?

Comment: @CeemahFour yes, it didn't help